# Javascript in Django template

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, solr

I am writing a template which renders the output of a search through Solr/Scorched in Django. Some of the results' links should point to another page (another template), in which I'd like to run a javascript. I have already succeeded in passing the data in the search-template:

```
<a href="{% url 'myview' result.pk %}" class="myclass" data-mydata="{{ result.mydata }}">Go</a>
```

The page this link points contains an image visualiser, and I would like the landing page to be already in the correct image in the viewer (and not always the first one). I already have a working script in the page with the visualiser: when I click one of the items within that page it jumps to the corresponding image.

I can I tell Django, from the search-results-template, to use the data- within the href for not only going to the visualiser-page, but also to go to the correct image?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended up using the [Web Api storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API), storing data-mydata (without using the {{ verbatim }} tag, which invalidates it) in sessionStorage and calling it back on a script in the landing page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `{% verbatim %}` template tag around your JavaScript handlebars. [Ref to the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#verbatim). I don't know all the details to your project, but generally it's considered bad practice to mix server-side and client-side rendering.

```
<a href="{% url 'myview' result.pk %}" class="myclass" {% verbatim %} data-mydata="{{ result.mydata }}" {% endverbatim %}>Go</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It still doesn't work though - it goes to the correct page but it doesn't run the js there. Moreover "it's considered bad practice to mix server-side and client-side rendering" -> what would do a better way to do this, then? It's my first Django project so I'm happy to hear suggestions/way of improving.

Comment: PS: another solution would perhaps be that of populating the input form (on the landing page) with the image number passed via the 'data-' parameter and send a 'enter' command. Would that be possible?